# PHP If else if not working correctly

Tags: php

When I click y link,it is going to x.Why is that ?

```
<a href="test.php?hello=x">x</a>
    <a href="test.php?hello=y">y</a>
    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) == 'x')
    {
    echo 'x';
    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) == 'y'){
    echo 'y';
    }
    else
    {
    echo "else";
    }
```

Comment: You really need to brush up on the basics of PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns either `true` or `false` and you are comparing that return value with strings `'x'` and `'y'`.

Since you are using `==` and not `===`, `true == 'x'` will return `ture`.

To fix this first you need to check if the variable is set and only then compare it.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) && ($_REQUEST['hello']) === 'x'))
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) && ($_REQUEST['hello']) == 'x')   )
```

Comment: first you should use `isset` and then you should compare values :)

Answer (score 0):

`isset` returns `true` or `false`, in both of these examples `hello` is set to *something*, so `isset` would return `true` (which does not equate to either `x` or `y`)

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) &&  $_REQUEST['hello']== 'x')
        {
        echo 'x';
        }
        else if(isset($_REQUEST['hello']) && $_REQUEST['hello'] == 'y'){
        echo 'y';
        }
        else
        {
        echo "else";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

isset will check whether the request is set or not returns 0 or 1

```
<a href="test.php?hello=x">x</a>
<a href="test.php?hello=y">y</a>
<?php
if($_REQUEST['hello'] == 'x')
{
echo 'x';
}
else if($_REQUEST['hello'] == 'y'){
echo 'y';
}
else
{
echo "else";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $myvar = $_REQUEST['hello'];


if($myvar == 'x')
{
echo 'x';
}
else if($myvar == 'y')
{
    echo 'y';
}
else
{
    echo 'else';
}

?>
```

Try this one